# Passing data through didSelectRowAtIndexPath, crash error when displaying in detail view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm passing data through didSelectRowAtIndexPath (three values in particular: users name, bio and photo) to my detail view controller.

The data passes successfully to my NSDictionary, neigbourDetail, but when trying to display it in my detail view in a label (OtherUserViewController), this line causes a crash error:

**OtherUserViewController.m**

```
self.username.text = [[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"users_name"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

**The crash error is:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString
>   objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xa00bc50441082e58'

I can't seem to sort out why. See below initial View, and data returned in OtherUserViewController (detail view). How should I be writing the crashing line instead?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    OtherUserViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

     vc.neighbourDetail= self.neighbourData[indexPath.row][@"userbio"];
     vc.neighbourDetail= self.neighbourData[indexPath.row][@"photo_path"];
     vc.neighbourDetail= self.neighbourData[indexPath.row][@"users_name"];


    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    [navController setViewControllers: @[vc] animated: YES];

    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];

}
```

**Data returned**

```
2016-04-14 14:59:30.877 myapp[5396:1739868] This is the neighbourdata (
        {
        address = "Address is here";
        "photo_path" = "http://url.com/default/files/stored/1459887925.jpg";
        "profile photo" = "<img typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"http://url.com/default/files/stored/1459887925.jpg\" width=\"750\" height=\"732\" alt=\"\" />";
        uid = 47;
        userbio = "Hi my name is Blair";
        "users_name" = Blair;
    },
```

Comment: You aren't passing a dictionary to `neighbourDetail`, you're setting it to three different strings.  Just do `vc.neightbourDetail = self.neighbourData[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Your `self.username.text = [[neighbourDetail objectForKey:@"users_name"] objectAtIndex:0];` is also going to crash because your "users_name" is a string and not an array

Comment: @dan Thank you! :) Fixed.